# Gatsby Tutorial Part 3: Can't Get Typography Plugin to Work

Tags: plugins, gatsby

I've followed the instructions here [gatsby tutorial:3](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-three/) under the "Using Gatsby Plugins" section. But I can't get the fairy theme to appear. The `<style>` element never gets added to the `<head>` element. My only guess is this warning I get within the typography.js:

Could not find a declaration file for module 'typography-theme-fairy-gates'. 'c:/Users/jghof/tutorial-part-three/node_modules/typography-theme-fairy-gates/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/typography-theme-fairy-gates` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'typography-theme-fairy-gates';`ts(7016)

I don't understand what this means or how to fix it as I'm very new to this stuff, and the tutorial has not said anything about this issue. I tried the npm install suggestion just for the heck of it but I just got a bunch of errors in the terminal. Could anyone help?

**Edit:** 
I found 4 problems within VSCode related to this file: tutorial-part-three\node_modules\typography-theme-fairy-gates\src\index.js

these are the problems it lists:

'import ... =' can only be used in a .ts file.

'=' expected.

';' expected.

'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

they occur on line 3 and 7 of the file. I can't figure out how to fix any of this, but here's the file below.

```js
// @flow
import gray from "gray-percentage"
import type { OptionsType } from "Types"
import { MOBILE_MEDIA_QUERY } from "typography-breakpoint-constants"
import verticalRhythm from "compass-vertical-rhythm"

const theme: OptionsType = {
  title: "Fairy Gates",
  baseFontSize: "20px",
  baseLineHeight: 1.45,
  googleFonts: [
    {
      name: "Work Sans",
      styles: ["600"],
    },
    {
      name: "Quattrocento Sans",
      styles: ["400", "400i", "700"],
    },
  ],
  headerFontFamily: ["Work Sans", "sans-serif"],
  bodyFontFamily: ["Quattrocento Sans", "sans-serif"],
  headerColor: "hsla(0,0%,0%,0.9)",
  bodyColor: "hsla(0,0%,0%,0.8)",
  headerWeight: "600",
  bodyWeight: 400,
  boldWeight: 700,
  overrideStyles: ({ adjustFontSizeTo, scale, rhythm }, options) => {
    const linkColor = "#1ca086"
    const vr = verticalRhythm({
      baseFontSize: "17px",
      baseLineHeight: "24.65px",
    })
    return {
      a: {
        color: linkColor,
        textDecoration: "none",
        textShadow:
          ".03em 0 #fff,-.03em 0 #fff,0 .03em #fff,0 -.03em #fff,.06em 0 #fff,-.06em 0 #fff,.09em 0 #fff,-.09em 0 #fff,.12em 0 #fff,-.12em 0 #fff,.15em 0 #fff,-.15em 0 #fff", // eslint-disable-line
        backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 1px, ${linkColor} 1px, ${linkColor} 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 2px)`, // eslint-disable-line
      },
      "a:hover,a:active": {
        textShadow: "none",
        backgroundImage: "none",
      },
      "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6": {
        marginTop: rhythm(1.5),
        marginBottom: rhythm(0.5),
      },
      // Blockquote styles.
      blockquote: {
        ...scale(1 / 5),
        borderLeft: `${rhythm(6 / 16)} solid ${linkColor}`,
        color: gray(35),
        paddingLeft: rhythm(10 / 16),
        fontStyle: "italic",
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginRight: 0,
      },
      "blockquote > :last-child": {
        marginBottom: 0,
      },
      "blockquote cite": {
        ...adjustFontSizeTo(options.baseFontSize),
        color: options.bodyColor,
        fontStyle: "normal",
        fontWeight: options.bodyWeight,
      },
      "blockquote cite:before": {
        content: '"— "',
      },
      [MOBILE_MEDIA_QUERY]: {
        html: {
          ...vr.establishBaseline(),
        },
        blockquote: {
          borderLeft: `${rhythm(3 / 16)} solid ${linkColor}`,
          color: gray(41),
          paddingLeft: rhythm(9 / 16),
          fontStyle: "italic",
          marginLeft: rhythm(-3 / 4),
          marginRight: 0,
        },
      },
    }
  },
}

export default theme
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same issue. I was able to fix it by installing the typography module.

`npm i -S typography`

Answer (score 0):

If there are no types available for a library, you can use `const fairyGates = require("typography-theme-fairy-gates")` or add a new declaration in a separate `.d.ts` file.

Comment: (Doesn't the second part suggestion just repeat what the message said?)

Comment: Hi Jon. This problem I think was just a syntax error on my part with some random braces somewhere. They deleted my post where I said I just tried a bunch of stuff and reinstalled this and it worked (I guess they thought it wasn't constructive.) But this is not an issue for me anymore, and quite frankly this entire question should probably just disapear as I'm pretty sure it was a complete syntactical error on my part. Thanks for your response though.

Answer (score 0):

it's most likely an error from the typography-theme-fairy-gates module

https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typography.js/issues/279

you can continue with  typography-theme-kirkham instead